# Android equalizer

Tags: android, audio, visualizer, equalizer

I'm not even sure that equalizer is the right name for it. Basically i need to show sound wavering, like in screenshot below:

[image]

I was looking throw stack, and googling, overall i found this library:
https://github.com/steelkiwi/AndroidRecording

What i've achieved using it is : 
[image]

As you can see it's just previous result just fading and new one is drawing above it on canvas. This is achieved using android class `Visualizer`(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html)

But what i need is to gather and show both previous and new data by moving canvas like this:

[image]

And also i need to store all this data somewhere to then show it all in `Play` mode, or just something that will show full data of audio while playing(not only part like now)

***Summary:*** In theory i can move canvas and drawig data manually, which i don't want to do, because i'll lose some time on optimizing drawing and making the whole thing. Also, it won't resolve my issue with playing, because data only for current moment will be sent to visualizer. So i need something like library or advice from someone, who worked with the same or similar functionality

**If something is unclear, please ask your question in comments**